# How to merge a nested object with parent in marshmallow (+ sqlalchemy)?

Tags: python, marshalling

From their example https://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#nesting-serializers

How do you get a merged result instead of nested?
Expected result:

```
user = User(name="Monty", email="monty@python.org")
blog = Blog(title="Something Completely Different", author=user)
serialized = BlogSerializer(blog)
serialized.data
# {'created_at': 'Sun, 10 Nov 2013 16:10:57 -0000',
#  'email': u'monty@python.org',
#  'name': u'Monty',
#  'title': u'Something Completely Different'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the way Marshmallow serialises objects I decided to use the data_handler.
It may seem like a hack (tbh, it is) but I really need the data flatten.

This solution has the advantage it is easy to remove the *hack* once I don't need it.

```
@BlogSerializer.data_handler
def flatten(serializer, data, obj):
    if 'author' in data:
        author = data['author']
        del data['author']
        return dict(author, **data)
    else:
        return data
```

You could easily make this method more generic, with a list of attributes to flatten. I don't need that level of abstraction at the moment.

Thanks @justanr for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to serialize each property of the nested object separately. The easiest way, if you wanted to go this route, would be to define a method field for each field you wanted "merged" into the main serializer. Although, with enough hacking on a custom field could manage this for you.

However, this plays against marshmallow's strength of allow you to easily and quickly composing complex schemas.

Comment: Thanks, I added code for the solution I'm using atm ;)